# Save Exif metadata while converting TIFF to PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, tiff, exif

How can you convert the metadata saved in the TIFF file (in EXIF format) when you convert your TIFF to a PDF?

For example, in the TIFF file, I can see the camera model used to make the picture. When I make a PDF based on this TIFF, I seem to lose this information. Is there a way to embed this information in the PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you should be able to read the exif data from the tiff file, re-encode it to XMP format and add it as a stream object to the metadata entry of the image stream in the PDF.

I believe that Adobe Photoshop and/or Illustrator will do this; I'm not sure that there are other tools to do this. Or, what other tools will extract that XMP metadata information from a PDF image.